# Construct intervals from a sequence of numbers and vice versa

Tags: python, python-3.x, interval

What is a Pythonic way to construct intervals from a sequence of integer numbers? E.g. sequence `[1, 2, 3, 6, 7, 9]` could be converted to `['1-3', '6-7', '9']`. I have implemented it like this:

```
def sequence_to_intervals(seq):
    intervals = []
    interval_start = None
    interval_end = None
    for i in sorted(seq):
        if interval_start is None:
            interval_start = i
            interval_end = i
        elif interval_end + 1 >= i:
            interval_end = i
        else:
            if interval_start == interval_end:
                intervals.append(str(interval_start))
            else:
                intervals.append(f'{interval_start}-{interval_end}')
            interval_start = i
            interval_end = i
    else:
        if interval_start == interval_end:
            intervals.append(str(interval_start))
        else:
            intervals.append(f'{interval_start}-{interval_end}')
    return intervals
```

Simple test:

```
seq = [1, 2, 3, 6, 7, 9]
sequence_to_intervals(seq)
['1-3', '6-7', '9']
```

Converting intervals back to sequence:

```
def intervals_to_sequence(intervals):
    seq = []
    for interval in intervals:
        if '-' in interval:
            start, stop = interval.split('-')
            seq += list(range(int(start), int(stop) + 1))
        else:
            seq += [int(interval)]
    return seq
```

Simple test:

```
intervals = ['1-3', '6-7', '9']
intervals_to_sequence(intervals)
[1, 2, 3, 6, 7, 9]
```

Comment: `interval_end is None` is never true.

Comment: @bipll Good remark. Should I remove this check from my question?

Comment: Yes, makes sense.

Answer (score 1):

For the first part of making sequence to intervals, you could do this instead (prob. more Pythonic?)  (This can be converted to a function easier - leave for the exercise)

```
>>> # if x-1 not in seq:  x becomes start point
>>> # if y+1 not in seq:  y becomes end point
>>> starts = [x for x in seq if x-1 not in seq]
>>> ends =  [y for y in seq if y+1 not in seq]
>>> ends
[3, 7, 9]
>>> intervals = [str(a)+'-'+str(b) for a, b in zip(starts, ends)]
>>> intervals
['1-3', '6-7', '9-9']
>>>
```

[Note - last interval could be 'fixed' too  - if we see start_point == end_point. Leave as an exercise.]

Then for the second part, it would be quite similar:

```
>>> seq = []
>>> for inter in intervals:
    s, e = inter.split('-')
    seq += list(range(int(s), int(e)+1))
>>> seq
[1, 2, 3, 6, 7, 9]
```

Comment: Please read a couple of well received answers "in tags" that interest you, then revisit [How do I write a Good Answer?](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer) to get the knack of what CodeReview@SE answers should be about - as with [your first answer](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/253157), your observation is about the problem where it should be about the code put up for review.

Comment: (When presenting code, "ready for cut, paste&run" has its advantages. Granted, "one of the conventional prompts" boosts confidence this is cut&pasted from an interactive session and actually works as far as demonstrated. Which made me wonder how interval '9' could have passed and notice your alternative solution uses a deviating, but not erroneous format.)